# InfluxDB port already in use

Tags: influxdb, rhel7

I need to install InfluxDB 2.0 in RHEL7. I followed [the installation guide](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/install/?t=Linux) from the InfluxDB website.

The `influxd` service gets running. However when I re-run `influxd`, it throws the following error.

```
Error: listen tcp :8086: bind: address already in use
```

However, `netstat -a | grep 8086` returns nothing.

When I change the port to 8087 by adding an argument to `/etc/default/influxdb2` and `/lib/systemd/system/influxdb.service`, `influxd` command works fine.

However, `influx setup` command throws an error now (this worked fine when the port was 8086).

I uninstalled and retried, but get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `netstat` will attempt to determine and display host and port names rather than displaying their numerical value. You can disable port resolution and display numerical port values by including the flag `--numeric-ports` (or `--numeric`/`-n` to disable the resolution of ports AND hosts.)

For the purposes of debugging, it may also be helpful to only return listening sockets and include the PID of the process that is listening.

You may want to try running `netstat -anlpt`.

- `-a`: all interfaces
- `-n`: show numerical addresses
- `-l`: only listening sockets
- `-p`: show the PID and program the socket belongs to
- `-t`: TCP only

You might also want to look at using `lsof`, which allows you to supply a port or list of ports along with the protocol: `lsof -P -itcp:8086`

It seems very likely that the InfluxDB service is already running and that you don't need to run `influxd` again.

Comment: Yes, in fact you were correct. Influxd had been running already on port 8086 and there wasn't a need to rerun 'influxd' command again. I think I misinterpreted a part in the guide. 'netstat -anlpt' provided the required information. Thank you so much.